# ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable (When uploading the file by using the CloudFIleOperationUtil )

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, xpath-2.0, serenity-bdd

I'm writing the script for uploading a file by using the `CloudFIleOperationUtil`.
But I'm getting the element not interactable error.

```
 String uploadFile = "//div[@id='dZUpload']";
 String absolutePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\resources\\uploadFiles\\" + file;
 CloudFileOperationUtil.uploadFileToCloud(uploadFile,absolutePath,getDriver());
```

The same code is working fine when the element is present in the Input tag. But not working when the element is present in the div tag.

Normally the element is clickable only. But when I passing as a parameter the element inside the upload File To Cloud method, I get an error.

So, how can I interact with the element that is present inside the div tag?

Comment: your locator should be targeting an <input type="file"> element.